# How not to render in Razor?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I have the following piece of code in my _Layout.cshtml:

```
<main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                @RenderBody()
                <a id="Logout" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout">Logout</a>
            }
            else
            {
                <a id="Login" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login">Login</a>
            }
        </main>
```

When I run my app, I get the following exception: **RenderBody has not been called for the page at '/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml'. To ignore call IgnoreBody().**

Is there any way not to render a component in Razor?

Thank you for any advice!!!!

Comment: Have you tried adding `@IgnoreBody()` in the `else` clause?

Comment: Yes, and compiler says : "Cannot implicitly convert void to object"

Comment: Try this: `@{ IgnoreBody() }`

Comment: @AntonToshik ,"Unexpected "{" after "@" character. Once inside the body of a code block (@if {}, @{}, etc.) you do not need to use "@{" to switch to code."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ignore the body,change like below:

```
<main role="main" class="pb-3">
    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        @RenderBody()
        <a id="Logout" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout">Logout</a>
    }
    else
    {
        IgnoreBody();
        <a id="Login" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login">Login</a>
    }
</main>
```